# Template is not rendering data from angular controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have constructed the following routes in angular.

ROUTES

```
var app = angular.module("app",['ngRoute']);
app.config([

'$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/items/', {
            templateUrl: '/app/items/index.html',
            controller: 'ItemsController'
        })
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/app/home/index.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })

}
]);
```

Each route has its own template and a controller.

TEMPLATES

items/index.html

```
<h2>Items</h2>

<div ng-repeat ="item in items">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

home/index.html

```
<h2>Home</h2>

<p>{{message}}</p>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>Configuration and Routing</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href ="bootstrap.min.css">

    <base href="/" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class ="container">
        <h1>Configuration and Routing</h1>
        <div class = "navbar">
            <ul class ="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/items">Items</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div ng-view>
            <h4>{{ message }}</h4>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script src = "angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="./app/app.js"></script>


  </body >

 </html>
```

CONTROLLERS

ItemsController

```
app.controller('ItemsController',[
   '$scope',
   function($scope) {

      $scope.items = ['First','Second','Third']
   }
])
```

HomeController

```
app.controller('HomeController', [
  '$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Welcome!';

  }
]);
```

The problem i have is the browser shows only the partial templates but not the data(i.e 'message' and 'items') from the controllers which it is supposed to show under the div with ng-view attribute.I also get the  following errors from the browser "Argument 'HomeController'  and ItemsController is not a function got undefined".

How can i resolve this ?

Comment: It seems your controllers aren't loaded. Are there in separate .js files? Do you use a web bundler? If no, you must probably include your files in your main template: `<script src ="./app/ItemsController.js"></script>`

Comment: The controllers are in separate files.Let me include them in the main template.

Comment: Thank  you @sjahan.That was the problem.After adding the scripts for both controllers,the problem was resolved.

Comment: Glad to help, have a good day @briin ;)